# Locally constant function vs step function

Tags: functions

I'm teaching myself mathematics and am not sure I understand the definition of a [locally constant function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_constant_function).

Am I correct in thinking that a locally constant function is just a step function with the points at the steps removed and without limit on the number of steps?

So a locally constant function is never a step function and vice-versa, but they are very similar?

Comment: If $f\colon I\to \mathbb{R}$ is locally constant on an interval $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is constant. So, trivially, it's a step function. If $I$ is a union of disjoint intervals then, yes, $f$ is like what you describe: a step function with the step-points removed. In any case, $f$ can be have only countably many values (pick a rational in each interval on which $f$ is constant).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a locally constant function. Notice how every point is surrounded by points of the same height:

[image: locally constant function]

Here is a rectangular function, a type of step function. Notice how there are 2 points that are not surrounded by points of the same height:

[image: rectangular function]

Because there are points where the function is defined, but the derivative is not $0$ (it's undefined), it is not a locally constant function.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\leq 0 \\ 1&x> 0\end{cases}$$
This is a step function. It's not locally constant since there is no neighborhood of $0$ s.t. $f$ is constant. So, locally constant is a stronger restriction than to be only a step function.

Comment: Thank you. So $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0 \\ 1 & x>0 \end{cases}$$ is a step function? There's no requirement for step functions to be defined everywhere?

Comment: yes it is. And if you need to prolonge it on $\mathbb R$ you can set $f(0)=a$ for any $a\in\mathbb R$. But, $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x<0\\ 1&x>0\\\infty &x=0\end{cases}$$ is not a step function.